# How can I find out why subprocess.Popen wait() waits forever if stdout=PIPE?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program that writes to stdout and possibly stderr. I want to run it from python, capturing the stdout and stderr. My code looks like:

```
from subprocess import *

p = Popen( exe, shell=TRUE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE )
rtrncode = p.wait()
```

For a couple of programs, this works fine, but when I added a new one, the new one hangs forever. If I remove `stdout=PIPE`, the program writes its output to the console and finishes and everything is fine. How can I determine what's causing the hang?

Using python 2.5 on Windows XP. The program does not read from stdin nor does it have any kind of user input (i.e. "hit a key").

Answer (score 53, accepted):

When a pipe's buffer fills up (typically 4KB or so), the writing process stops until a reading process has read some of the data in question; but here you're reading nothing until the subprocess is done, hence the deadlock.  [The docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on `wait` put it very clearly indeed:

> **Warning** This will deadlock if the
>   child process generates enough output
>   to a stdout or stderr pipe such that
>   it blocks waiting for the OS pipe
>   buffer to accept more data. Use
>   communicate() to avoid that.

If you can't use `communicate` for some reason, have the subprocess write to a temporary file, and then you can `wait` and read that file when it's ready -- writing to a file, instead of to a pipe, does not risk deadlock.

Comment: You beat me to it by a bit. +1

Comment: The help file installed with python 2.5 doesn't have that little tidbit of information. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait). It states that you shouldn't use wait as it can cause a dead lock. Try using [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate).