# Python, subprocess, devenv, why no output?

Tags: python, subprocess

I build a Visual Studio solution from a Python script. Everything works nicely, except that I am unable to capture the build output.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['devenv', 'solution.sln', '/build'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
ret = p.returncode
```

Here, both `out` and `err` are always empty. This happens regardless of the build success as seen in `p.returncode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should build the solution with `msbuild.exe` instead, which is designed to give feedback to stdout and stderr. `msbuild.exe` is located at

`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\msbuild.exe` (to build a VS2005 solution)
or `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe` (to build a VS2008 solution)

Note that `msbuild.exe` does not take a `/build` switch like `devenv.exe`.

Comment: I know that this is an question but I thought I would comment on this for other's benefit. Yes you can accomplish this with msbuild and it's a very nice tool. But if you have a solution that builds VS setup projects, msbuild does NOT build those projects. I have python scripts that build some of my solutions and then distribute setups to servers and my own archive but I'm unable to use msbuild. I'm going to give devenv.com a try and see if I can get errors that way and I think that would be ideal for me and my situation.

Answer (score 27):

Change it from 'devenv' to 'devenv.com'.  Apparenty Popen looks for .EXEs first but the shell looks for .COMs first. Switching to 'devenv.com' worked for me.

devenv is significantly faster then msbuild for incremental builds. I just did a build with an up to date project, meaning nothing should happen.

devenv 23 seconds
msbuild 55 seconds.

Comment: I believe the speed difference was that `devenv` defaults to parallel build where MSBuild isn't. Try `msbuild /m` and you should see similar speed.

Comment: +1 for devenv.com.  That's what worked for me.  MSBUILD is not available for VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the software you're running doesn't write to `stdout` or `stderr`. Maybe it [writes directly to the terminal/console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687403(VS.85).aspx).

If that's the case you'll need some [win32 api calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961(VS.85).aspx) to capture the output.

Comment: In this case, would I not see the build output on the screen when I run my script?

Comment: @Gilad: I don't know. Maybe you have to print it back yourself.

Comment: If you want to capture the output you can use the /out flag with and follow it with a log file path. The build events are then logged to that file.

Answer (score -2):

Probably your problem is the same that the pipe's buffer fills up. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445627/how-can-i-find-out-why-subprocess-popen-wait-waits-forever-if-stdoutpipe) for a good answer.

Comment: No, the problem in that case would be a hang, and the solution to is to use p.communicate(). The OP doesn't experience a hang and already uses p.communicate().